# nested form with jquery error :- new value overwriting previous selected values in the partial

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Well i am trying to do a dynamic combo select inside a partial. and the value of the batch no stays the same, ie whatever batch no i select in first partial rest of the partial has the same value.

Code is as follows

Form

```
<%= nested_form_for(@bill) do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.link_to_add "add product", :bill_line_items %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

the partial

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'testing' %>
  <div class ="kool">

  <div class ="name"><%= f.label :product_id %>
<%= f.collection_select :product_id,Product.all ,:id,:name, :style => 'width:150px;'%></div><br />

    <div class="list">
    <%= f.label :batch_no %><br />
    <%= f.grouped_collection_select :batch_no, Product.all, :store_opening_stocks, :id, :batch_no, :batch_no %><br/></div>

  </div>
```

Js File

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       var batchNo = jQuery('.list').html();

  jQuery('.name').bind('change',function() {

     var  productSelected = jQuery('.name:selected').val();

   var options = jQuery(batchNo).find("optgroup[label='" + productSelected + "']").html();

     jQuery('.list select').html(options);

            });
          });
```

Screen Shots before selecting product

[image: before Selecting the product]

Screen Shot After selecting product and clicking on Add product

[image: after selecting product and clicking add product]

Screen shot after Reselecting product again

[image: Reselecting product again]

as you can see the Product-2 group i'e P1 and P2(batch nos of product 2) coming in second and third partial. and any attempt to change product, the batch nos show empty as shown in the picture.

how do i solve this problem?? should i use `Parent` somewhere or `this` option?? Guidance required.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Post the HTML that the client gets, not the server code.

Comment: Everything i have posted is on client side of rails. i will post the HTML codes of the rails in just a bit.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/qTFjVBBy hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. it will help. use the parent element to get the value of that particular form. in this case parent is `kool` and getJSON method is better prefered than this method so your code will be something like this.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
jQuery(".prod select").bind("change", function() {
      var data = {
        product_id: jQuery(this).val()  
      }
      var wrapperDivElement = jQuery(this).parents(".kool");
      jQuery.getJSON(
         "/customer_bills/get_batch",
        data,
        function(data){
      var result = "",a;
      var b = "<option>Select Batch no</option>"
      for(i=0;i<data.length; i++)
      {
       a = data[i];  
       result = result + "<option value="+a[0]+">"+a[0]+"</option>";
      }
       jQuery('.batch select', wrapperDivElement).html(b+result);
      });            
        });
    });
```

in controller

```
def get_batch
    @product_batch = StoreOpeningStock.find_all_by_product_id(params[:product_id]).map{|p| [p.batch_no, p.price]} if params[:product_id]
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @product_batch }
    end
  end
```

and in routes

```
resources :customer_bills do
    collection do
      get :get_batch
    end
  end
```

this method is much more clear and better. all the best :)